# How to show color picker in grid cell?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I try to show colorpicker in grid cell. But i can't do it correct. It must look like show/hide panel whith colorpiker and save piked color in grid cell.

I try to use several controls. But allways have problems. Please explain to do it right way.

Now it's look like this:

[image: Color picker]

and the code:

```
{
    xtype: "widgetcolumn",
    dataIndex: "color",
    text: "Color",
    width: 60,

    widget: {
        xtype: 'colorpicker',
        align: 'right',
        value: '993300',
    },

    listeners: {
        select: function(picker, selColor) {
            value = selColor,
                hide(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Matthias Eckhart! I have low reputation to post pictures like you!

Comment: probably you have to use 'editor' of column.

Comment: "use 'editor' of column" try it, don't work. May be i do it wrong way. Show correct example please!

Comment: create working jsfiddle for your grid and I will add color picker to it ;)

Comment: create fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home please change it right way.

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/qra

Comment: I first time work with fiddle. And new in frontend development.

Comment: Final fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/qra

Comment: please have a look on this https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/qtf

Comment: Thank you but it dosen,t work in ext 5.1. We will migrate to 6.0 later. Do you know why it can dosen't work in 5.1? Sorry for my english) It set "Uncaught TypeError: e.setValue is not a function" in ext.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    show color picker in grid cell.double click on grid row then select menu bar color and click on update plugin color show on grid row.code check in js fiddler





  Ext.onReady(function () {
                    var userStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                        autoLoad: 'false',
                        fields: [
                            { name: 'name' },
                            { name: 'email' },
                            { name: 'colorCode' }
                        ],
                        data: [
                            { name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com'},
                            { name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com'},
                            { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com'},
                            { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com'},
                            { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com' },
                            { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com'},
                        ]
                    });

                    var customColors = ['FF4848', 'FF7575', 'FFA8A8', 'FFBBBB', 'FFCECE', 'FFECEC', 'FF68DD', 'FF86E3', 'FFACEC', 'FFC8F2', 'FF62B0', 'FF73B9', 'FF86C2', 'FFA8D3',
          'E469FE', 'EA8DFE', 'EFA9FE', 'D568FD', 'D97BFD', 'DD88FD', 'E7A9FE', '9669FE', 'A27AFE', 'C4ABFE', 'D0BCFE', 'DDCEFF', 'FFA4FF', 'EAA6EA', 'D698FE', 'CEA8F4',
          'BCB4F3', 'A9C5EB', '8CD1E6', 'FFBBFF', 'EEBBEE', 'DFB0FF', 'DBBFF7', 'CBC5F5', 'BAD0EF', 'A5DBEB', 'FFCEFF', 'F0C4F0', 'E8C6FF', 'E1CAF9', 'D7D1F8', 'CEDEF4',
          'B8E2EF', '62A9FF', '62D0FF', '06DCFB', '01FCEF', '03EBA6', '01F33E', '99E0FF', '63E9FC', '74FEF8', '62FDCE', '72FE95', 'C0F7FE', 'CEFFFD', 'BEFEEB', 'CAFFD8',
          '1FCB4A', '59955C', '48FB0D', '2DC800', '59DF00', '9D9D00', 'B6BA18', 'DFDF00', 'DFE32D', '93EEAA', 'A6CAA9', 'AAFD8E', '6FFF44', 'ABFF73', 'FFFF84', 'E7F3F1',
          'EEF093', 'BDF4CB', 'C9DECB', 'CAFEB8', 'A5FF8A', 'D1FFB3', 'FFFFB5', 'F5F7C4', 'BABA21', 'C8B400', 'DFA800', 'DB9900', 'FFB428', 'FF9331', 'FF800D', 'D8F0F8',
          'E6E671', 'E6CE00', 'FFCB2F', 'FFB60B', 'FFC65B', 'FFAB60', 'FFAC62', 'F7DE00', 'FFD34F', 'FFBE28', 'FFCE73', 'FFBB7D', 'FFBD82', 'EEEECE', 'EADFBF', 'E4C6A7',
          'E6C5B9', 'DEB19E', 'E8CCBF', 'DDB9B9', 'E1E1A8', 'DECF9C', 'DAAF85', 'DAA794', 'CF8D72', 'DAAC96', 'D1A0A0', 'FF8E8E', 'E994AB', 'FF7DFF', 'D881ED', 'B7B7FF',
          'A6DEEE', 'CFE7E2', 'FFC8C8', 'F4CAD6', 'FFA8FF', 'EFCDF8', 'C6C6FF', 'C0E7F3', 'DCEDEA', 'FFEAEA', 'F8DAE2', 'FFC4FF', 'EFCDF8', 'DBDBFF'];
                    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                        height: 400,
                        width: 350,
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        layout: 'fit',
                        items:
                        [
                            {
                                layout: 'border',
                                height: 200,
                                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                                items:
                                   [

                              {
                                  xtype: 'grid',
                               //   height: 300,
                                  region: 'center',
                                  id: 'GridId',
                                  store: userStore,


                                  columns: [
                                      {
                                          header: 'Name',
                                          width: 100,
                                          sortable: false,
                                          hideable: false,
                                          dataIndex: 'name',
                                          editor: {
                                              xtype: 'textfield'
                                          }
                                      },
                                      {
                                          header: 'Email Address',
                                          width: 150,
                                          dataIndex: 'email',
                                          editor: {
                                              xtype: 'textfield',
                                          }
                                      },
                                       {
                                           header: 'Color',
                                           dataIndex: 'colorCode',
                                           width: '20%',
                                           renderer: function (value, metaData) {
                                               metaData.tdAttr = 'bgcolor=' + value;
                                               return value;
                                           },

                                           editor: {
                                               xtype: 'button',
                                               text: 'Color Menu',
                                               menu: new Ext.menu.ColorPicker({
                                                   resizable: true,
                                                   scrollable: true,
                                                   listeners: {
                                                       select: function (metaData, value) {
                                                           metaData.up('grid').getSelection()[0].dirty = true;
                                                           metaData.up('grid').getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].data.colorCode = value;
                                                       }
                                                   }
                                               }),
                                               listeners: {
                                                   render: function (metaData, value) {
                                                       metaData.down('colorpicker').colors = [];
                                                       metaData.down('colorpicker').value = metaData.ownerCt.context.grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].data.colorCode;
                                                       for (var i = 0; i < customColors.length; i++) {
                                                           metaData.down('colorpicker').colors.push(customColors[i]);
                                                       }
                                                       metaData.down('colorpicker').updateLayout();
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           }
                                       },

                                  ],
                                  selModel: 'rowmodel',
                                  plugins: {
                                      ptype: 'rowediting',
                                      clicksToEdit: 2
                                  },
                              }
                              ]


                            }]

                    }).show();
                });
```

Comment: It's works properly! absolutly! Only 1 moment selected color used by HighChart and it need color with # ("#FFFFFF") but it's not a problem)

Comment: how i can set any tipe of "like" to you?

Comment: @Anilkumar Your solution seems to work well when the selection model is rowmodel and the plugin type is rowedit. But in my case, I have checkbox model and my plugin type is celledit. The color appears but on trying to fetch the colorpicker menu, I get the following error: `g.setValue is not a function`. Any idea??  This is for EXTJS 6.0.1